# Meteor dynamic mongodb based on user

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I develop a multi tenant application where each tenant has its own mongo db.
All tenants share the same UI.

I should have one mongo db for all users accounts and each mongo db for data.

I'm new in meteor and i would like to know how i can dynamically select the database when i publish the collections.

```
    export const collects = new MongoObservable.Collection('collectionname',{
    connection:DDP.connect('urltomongodb')

});
```

Any help please

Comment: I don't believe you can do that easily, but you should be able to select your collections dynamically. Would that help?

Comment: Did you ever find any answers - solutions related with this one?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the DDP utilities are available for people who wish to connect to a Meteor server from a non-Meteor platform, either front end or server.

There is, of course, nothing to stop you using DDP.connect() to connect to another server, but you will also need to manage that connection, and any retries etc if it becomes unavailable.

I would suggest an easier path is to manage all of your data in one database - trying to separate them becomes non-trivial, because it is doing something that Meteor doesn't normally do. If you structure your data accordingly, it should be quite feasible to keep all the data in one database

Comment: I am having almost same question/issue and forcing multi tenant application to one database is not solution to be honest, especially if you have databases which are going to grown up to 50 GB easily

Comment: Maybe the solution for you is to provide data as a REST API, or you could use something like this: https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-directcollection (I have not tried it myself)